# Need help with my withdrawal

Tags: exchanges, withdrawal

If I used coinme to deposit at an atm can someone walk me through how to withdrawal? I have the coinme app and trust wallet? Which one would I use? Someone was helping me and stopped responding..

Desperately seeking help!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FAQ on the coinme website](https://coinme.com/how-to/#redeem-title)

> Any bitcoin or crypto purchase made through Coinme at one of our partner locations will be stored in your Coinme wallet.

They also have a [video explaining how to "sell Bitcoin for cash"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y1r75rckxw&t=23s)

---

You wrote

> Someone was helping me and stopped responding.

Frankly, that's a bit of a red flag. All too often that means somebody you met online tricked you and ran away with your money. I hope this isn't the case.

> Desperately seeking help!

Beware, don't pay any unexpected fees to people who offer to help you. Desperate people attract scammers pretending to be able to return stolen money, pretending to know someone who can return stolen money or pretending to be an official in charge of returning stolen money. I recommend reading a few answers to [questions tagged "fraud"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fraud)